# Why does UIPasteboard.general.string?.append("another") crash if UIPasteboard.general.string returns nil?

Tags: ios, uipasteboard

**Crash report:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIConcretePasteboard setString:]: Argument is not an object of type NSString [(null)]'
```

**Stack trace:**

```
0   CoreFoundation     0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
1   libobjc.A.dylib    0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation     0x00007fff23c710bc +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
3   UIKitCore          0x00007fff47fb21cd -[_UIConcretePasteboard setString:] + 185
4   UIPasteboardwack   0x0000000109a7bc40 $s16UIPasteboardwack14ViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyF + 816
```

**Steps:**

1. create a new project.
2. Do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   UIPasteboard.general.string?.append("We are appending first ")
}
```

3. quit simulator if its open.
4. run the app on a simulated *iPhone 8* or earlier.

[UIPasteboard documents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard)

[UIPasteboard source code](https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon/blob/master/UIKit/Classes/UIPasteboard.m)

**Background**
So it took me a while to figure out how to recreate this because there are cases where the string property isn't set, but still returns `Optional("")` such as when using iPhone 11 before setting a value to string.

Also, it would seem that if string returns nil, then the append method should silently fail.  I'm also not understanding how `setString` on `UIConcretePasteboard` is getting called.

Comment: I *suppose* documentation could be a bit more thorough, and it *does* seem like that should "fail silently." Although... one could argue that folks might spend more time trying to figure out why the string didn't get there. Probably better to check `.hasStrings` and then set or append as appropriate.

Comment: @DonMag, that is my current patch.  But, not understanding why this is happening, I'm concerned I can't know if the patch fully solves the issue.  I'll post my current patch.

Answer (score 1):

Until a complete answer is provided, this is my current patch.

```
import UIKit

extension UIPasteboard {

    ///This is a safe alternative to UIPasteboard's string setter property.
    ///While the string property is optional, if you assign the value nil, it will crash.
    func safe(set new: String) {
        string = new
    }

    ///Since the string property is a computed property, if you attempt to append to it, it won't silently fail when string returns nil, instead it will crash.
    func safe(append new: String) {
        if !hasStrings {
            safe(set: new)
        } else {
            string?.append(new)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not satisfied with this current answer because, while it is the safest thing I can think of, without understanding the root cause, I can't guarantee this solution.

Comment: Leave out the `|| string == nil` ... as per the docs *Do not use the string or strings properties to determine whether a pasteboard contains string data, because doing so consumes resources needlessly.*

Comment: hmmm...Why would a nil check be expensive? Oh well.  Removed.